# Seach in a list of dictionaries after a value in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I have saw solutions, but in this case after the first result the search is stopped. How Can I implement, that the search get all the dictionaries in the list with the searched value?

```
search_value = input()
match = next((l for l in cleaned_list if l['Name'] == search_value), None)
print(match)
```

This is not working with the following approach:

```
search_value = input()
match = next((l for l in cleaned_list if l['Schluesse'] == search_value), None)
for match in cleaned_list:
   print(match)
```

The data in the `cleaned_list`:

```
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '11.8', 'erfasste Faelle': '17', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '4', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '9', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '44.4', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '0', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9277', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '14', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '2', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '52.9', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Rottal-Inn', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '9', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '9'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '22.2', 'erfasste Faelle': '9', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '2', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '4', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '50.0', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '1', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9278', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '9', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '2', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '44.4', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Straubing-Bogen', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '4', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '3'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '17.6', 'erfasste Faelle': '17', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '6', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '14', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '42.9', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '1', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9279', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '18', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '3', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '70.6', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Dingolfing-Landau', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '12', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '13'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '0.0', 'erfasste Faelle': '4', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '1', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '5', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '20.0', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '1', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9361', 'Kreisart': 'KfS', 'HZ nach Zensus': '10', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '0', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '100.0', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Amberg', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '4', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '4'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '4.4', 'erfasste Faelle': '45', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '9', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '21', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '42.9', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '7', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9362', 'Kreisart': 'KfS', 'HZ nach Zensus': '32', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '2', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '62.2', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Regensburg', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '28', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '14'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '0.0', 'erfasste Faelle': '8', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '4', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '0.0', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '1', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9363', 'Kreisart': 'KfS', 'HZ nach Zensus': '19', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '0', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '50.0', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Weiden i.d.OPf.', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '4', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '3'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '4.5', 'erfasste Faelle': '44', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '5', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '37', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '13.5', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '4', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9371', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '43', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '2', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '79.5', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Amberg-Sulzbach', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '35', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '33'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '0.0', 'erfasste Faelle': '48', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '33', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '45', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '73.3', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '3', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9372', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '38', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '0', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '93.8', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Cham', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '45', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '42'}
{'Versuche - Anteil in %': '1.6', 'erfasste Faelle': '64', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anzahl': '31', 'Tatverdaechtige insgesamt': '36', 'Nichtdeutsche Tatverdaechtige - Anteil in %': '86.1', 'mit Schusswaffe gedroht': '0', 'Tatverdaechtige - weiblich': '1', 'Gemeindeschluessel': '9373', 'Kreisart': 'LK', 'HZ nach Zensus': '50', 'Versuche - Anzahl': '1', 'Schluesse': '980100', 'Aufklaerungsquote': '93.8', 'Straftat': 'IuK-Kriminalität im engeren Sinne (SZ: 517500, 517900, 543000, 674200, 678000)', 'Stadt-/Landkreis': 'Neumarkt i.d.OPf.', 'mit Schusswaffe geschossen': '0', 'aufgeklaerte Faelle': '60', 'Tatverdaechtige - maennlich': '35'}
```

How can I now found the rows with `980100` in `Schluesse`(their other rows with other values in `Schluesse`

Comment: Please post your input and desired output.

Comment: The OP has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comprehension instead of the `next` call (which only gets you the first match) will do:

```
match = [l for l in cleaned_list if l['Schluesse'] == '980100']
for x in match:
    print(x)
```

Comment: That would indicate that there is only one match. How does your `cleaned_list` look and what is your `search_value`?

Comment: How can I print the matches, every line a match? I think it can be with a for loop. But If I make                 `match = [l for l in cleaned_list if l['Schluesse'] == search_value]
                for match in cleaned_list:
                    print(match)` the match is not the same match with the list comprehension

Comment: @madik_atma `match` is a list that you can now iterate. Added that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda d: d.get('Name') == search_value, cleaned_list)
```

will help you to produce the same sequence type as `cleaned_list` as well as ignore elements that don't have `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
final_data = [i for i in cleaned_list if i["Schluesse"] == '980100']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you often need this operation, it might be worth it to scan all your lists first and group them by `'Schluessel'`:

```
by_schluessel = {}
for l in cleaned_list:
    by_schluessel.setdefault(l['Schluesse'], []).append(l)

print(len(by_schluessel.get('980100', [])))
# 9
print(len(by_schluessel.get('980101', [])))
# 0
```

`by_schluessel` is a `dict` with `Schluesse` as key and a list of original dicts as value.
This query will be very fast once the grouping has been done.

By the way, a database or a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) might be more suitable for this kind of task.